# Checking focus in multiple frame fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, frame

I am using two frames inside a frameset on my `main.html` page.The source of the first frame is internal where the 2nd frame contains crossdomain source.In first frame i am showing a timer and in 2nd the content of cross domain.The timer only runs when the window is in focus otherwise(if you switch tabs or launch a new software ) it shows a warning message that window is out of focus.The problem i am facing is to make the focus fully workable.For example when i am clicking any content of the second frame then my code is detecting it as a lose of focus and showing the waring message though i am active on the current window(neither i switched tab nor launched any new application/software). How to solve this problem ?

Here is my code

Main.html

```
<script>
window.onload = function(){
document.getElementById('q1').focus();

}

</script>

<frameset rows="130,*" style="border: 1px #CC3333"  noresize="noresize" ">
<frame id="q1" name="showcountframe" src="count.html" scrolling=no marginheight="2" marginwidth="2"  noresize="noresize">
<frame name="showcontframe" src="gmail.com" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" noresize="noresize">
</frameset><noframes></noframes>
```

Count.html

```
  <script>
    var w_focus = true;

    window.onblur = function() {
      w_focus = false;
    }


    if(w_focus = true)

    {
    //code for running timer

    }
    else 
    {
      $('#warn').show();
    }
    <script>

    <div id="warn">Focus lost!</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, focus events are not well supported (is this an IE-only app?).  Depending on how your target browser interprets focus, it *may* be that clicking in the cross-site frame will raise a `blur` event for your timer frame, but not for the parent frame's `window` object, while clicking in a completely different window would raise both events.  If testing shows that to be the case, then you can use that to infer when the timer is hidden. (Except this likely wouldn't work in any case if your window is hidden by a popup / screensaver / etc)

Anyway, a better solution may be to use `window.requestAnimationFrame`.  That schedules code to be run whenever the browser is ready to do so, but an intentional side effect is that the scheduled code will not be invoked while the window is hidden.  So you can use `window.setInterval` (which always runs) to set a watchdog timer that checks whether the `window.requestAnimationFrame` callback has run; if it hasn't, you know that the window isn't visible.

#### Update: example

```
var timestamp = Date.now();

function ar () {
    timestamp = Date.now();
    window.requestAnimationFrame(ar);
}

function watchdog() {
  // show warning if ar() has not run for more than 2 seconds:
  if (Date.now() - timestamp > 2000)
      showHiddenWindowWarning();
  else dontShowHiddenWindowWarning();
}

ar(); // start requesting animation frames
window.setInterval (watchdog, 500); // check back twice a second
```

Comment: i am trying to achieve a cross browser support !however can you give  a simple example showing how i can use window.requestAnimationFrame ?